# Add one image per page with fpdf

Tags: php, image, addition, fpdf

I am trying to create a PDF document with one image per page with fpdf php library.

I can create a single page with image using:

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image($imagePath,10,10,0,0);
```

But the question is how to I move to a new page and add an image at the same co-ordinates but on page 2,3,etc

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the method `$pdf->AddPage();` again for starting an new page in the PDF document. The coordinate system will be reseted to the corner of the new page.

Example of an 3 page document:

```
$pdf = new FPDF();

//page 1
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image($imagePath,10,10,0,0);

//page 2
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image($imagePath,10,10,0,0);

//page 3
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image($imagePath,10,10,0,0);
```

From the manual:

> The origin of the coordinate system is at the top-left corner and
>   increasing ordinates go downwards.

But if the image need to be on every page, then I suggest **extending** the FPDF class and override the `header()` function.

> This method is used to render the page header. It is automatically
>   called by AddPage() and should not be called directly by the
>   application. The implementation in FPDF is empty, so you have to
>   subclass it and override the method if you want a specific processing.

[more info about the header function](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/header.htm)

Comment: Was looking for a solution in python but got the reference, thanks !!